# Run scrapy spider based on list of URLs passed to the spider through python script

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I get 1000 URLs from database along with 2 fields like name and id 
and my list looks like

```
[{'name':'name1','id':'id1,'link':'myurl1'},
 {'name':'name2','id':'id2,'link':'myurl2'},
 {'name':'name3','id':'id3,'link':'myurl3'},
 ...
 {'name':'name1000','id':'id1000,'link':'myurl1000'}
]
```

Now I want to create a spider to look up the `link` from the above list.
How can I pass the above list to a scrapy spider, process the `link` and return the respective `id` after processing.

EDIT:
I don't want spider to access the database

Comment: You need some primary key to update values in the database. so get that from the database too. After getting respective result, update the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in spider level the 
add a function `start_requests`. Query your db from start_requests function and for each item add a request and pass id in meta

You will get the link id from meta with response in your callback function. so do whatever you want with the response and id

but I recommend to write spider for 1 url and after you deployed your spider, shedule your spider for each url form your script. you can pass link id as argument and in pipeline you can do post crawl actions

Comment: I don't want my spider to qurey from database. I am looking that my spider should process based on the list.